# problem right syntax mysql php post request

Tags: php, mysql

I checked my syntax but i didn't finded any problems.

```
$donnees = json_decode($_POST['donnees']);
$ccd = json_decode($_POST['ccd']);


for($i=0; $i<count($donnees);$i++){


    $enregistrer=mysql_query("
                update
                    destrel as t1,
                    centres as t2 set t1.ercherche='".mysql_real_escape_string($donnees[$i]->er_cherche)."',
                    t1.ercapture='".mysql_real_escape_string($donnees[$i]->er_capture)."',
                    t1.erdebut='".mysql_real_escape_string($donnees[$i]->er_debut)."',
                    t1.erfin='".mysql_real_escape_string($donnees[$i]->er_fin)."',
                    t1.eraprog='".mysql_real_escape_string($donnees[$i]->er_aprogrammer)."'
                where 
                    t2.unite=$_SESSION[ogreuniteid] 
                    and t2.id=t1.centre
                    and t1.id='".mysql_real_escape_string($donnees[$i]->id)."'") or die("Impossible de lancer la requête : ".mysql_error());;

    if($enregistrer){

        echo("Enregistrement réussi");
    }
}
```

My error :

> Impossible de lancer la requête : You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'and t2.id=t1.centre and t1.id='625''
>   at line 10
>
> PHP version : 5.2.9 Mysql : 5.1.31

Thanks :)

EDIT : Solution :

$_SESSION was null so I launch session_start() and that so. 
Thank you guys !

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated, use mysqli_* or PDO, check this part of your code `t2.unite=$_SESSION[ogreuniteid] ` always php error_reporting on , this will help u to find errors

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Be sure to use prepared statements and parameter binding, so **you'll never have to worry about quoting issues again.**

Comment: not possible with this php version

Comment: It's a job project, i'm musted to use this versions

Comment: this will be closed soon, and your company will re develop this project :p

Comment: PDO was introduced in PHP 5.1.0 and mysqli was introduced in  5.0.0. You should have access to both, if it's compiled into the installation.

Comment: The problem isn't in the MySQL query, but in the way you assign a PHP variable to it. This results into the php variable to be put literally in the query. Have a good look at all variable assignments in your php code, fix the wrong one(s) and you will be enlightened.

Comment: yes thanks you guys ! @devpro was rigth. My $S_Session variable was null ... and I has never think was this

Comment: To troubleshoot your query as it stands, echo out your query and check it for any syntax errors.